# 投稿タグをカスタムフィールドの値で上書きしたい

Tags: wordpress

投稿タグを、特定の複数のカスタムフィールドの値に変更したいと考えています。
一つのカスタムフィールドだけをタグとして反映させることはできましたが、複数のカスタムフィールドの値をそれぞれタグとして反映させることができません。

これまで試したコードはこちらです

```php
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID; 
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); // here, adding array_filter to remove empty get_post_meta results
wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags, false );
?>
```

上記のコードの場合、一番上に記載したカスタムキーだけがタグに反映されました。

---

```php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID; 
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb', $single);
$tags[] = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
$tags = array_unique( array_filter( $tags ) ); // here, adding array_filter to remove empty get_post_meta results
foreach($tags as $tag){
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tag, false );
}
```

こちらのコードも一番上のカスタムキーだけがタグとして反映されました。

---

```php
<?php
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'aaaaa', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'bbbbb', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

$tags = get_post_meta($post_id, 'ccccc', $single);
if (!empty($tag) ) { wp_add_post_tags( $post_id, $$tag ); }

wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $tags, false );   

?>
```

上記のコードでは、カスタムフィールドの値はいずれもタグとして反映されませんでした。

Answer (score 1):

文字列で返ってきてないのが原因だったようで、第三引数trueであっさりうまくいきました！